# KafkaConnect elasticSearch Document Id Creation

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am currently using the following connector configuration and I am getting exception **"Key is used as document id and can not be null"**

```js
{

    "name" :"hello7",
    "config" : {
        "name": "hello7",
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "hello7",
        "connection.url":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/",
        "type.name":"aggregator",
        "schema.ignore": "true",
        "topic.schema.ignore": "true",
        "topic.key.ignore": "false",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false", 
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "key.ignore":"false",
        "transforms": "extractKey",
        "transforms.InsertKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
        "transforms.InsertKey.fields":"customerId",
        "transforms.extractKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
        "transforms.extractKey.field":"customerId",
        "errors.log.enable":true,
        "errors.log.include.messages":true

     }
}
```

and I am sending the following message to the topic

```
{

  "customerId" : "i7y32o4823",
  "customerName" : "JOE",
  "address":"123 main street",
  "employee" : "ABC Company",
  "employeeAddress" : "178 Main Street"

}
```

I am getting the following error

> 2020-01-17 16:28:33,624] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=hello7-0} Task threw
>   an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will
>   not recover until manually restarted.
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Key is used as
>   document id and can not be null.
>       at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.DataConverter.convertKey(DataConverter.java:79)
>       at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.DataConverter.convertRecord(DataConverter.java:160)
>       at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchWriter.tryWriteRecord(ElasticsearchWriter.java:285)
>       at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchWriter.write(ElasticsearchWriter.java:270)
>       at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.put(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:169)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set `"key.ignore":"false"` and only mentioned the value that you are sending to the Kafka topic.

Kafka records have both keys and values. If you don't specify a key, it will be null.

The Elasticsearch sink connector does not accept null keys, as the error says

> ConnectException: Key is used as document id and **can not be null**

In addition, you only extract the key in the transform, never using `InsertKey`

```
"transforms": "extractKey",
```

---

You can debug your connectors using standalone FileSinkConnector output to the console

```
name=local-console-sink
connector.class=org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=hello7
```